# Adding two separate Webpack dev server apps into subfolders using Docker and NGINX

Tags: nginx, webpack, docker-compose

I have `app1` and `app2`, both running with `webpack-dev-server` on separate ports. The client wants the apps under the same domain in different subfolders.

- domain.com/app/app1
- domain.com/app/app2

I set up a **`docker-compose.yml`** file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - './nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:ro'
```

Here's the **`nginx.conf`** file

```
upstream app1 {
  server host.docker.internal:5000;
}

upstream app2 {
  server host.docker.internal:5001;
}

server {
    listen              80;
    server_name         myapp;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_redirect      off;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header    Host localhost;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

   location /app/app1 {
      proxy_pass http://app1;
    }

    location /app/app2 {
      proxy_pass http://app2;
    }
}
```

I tried different webpack settings, but nothing seems to work. Here's the **`webpack.config.js`** for `app1`:

```
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 5000,
  },
```

When I visit `http://myapp/app/app1`, the index.html loads fine, but I get a 404 on the `main.js` script. The file is accessible at `http://myapp/app/app1/main.js`, but inside `index.html`, the script points to `main.js`, instead of `app/app1/main.js`.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>`

I tried changing `output.publicPath` in webpack, but then the script is no longer available. Is there a way to change the path inside the script tag without messing everything else up? Or how would I go about making this work when the app is running inside a subfolder?

Comment: `output.publicPath` should be a right solution, what wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, no thanks to the webpack docs. `historyApiFallback.index` needs to point to the same location as `publicPath`. Also, for hot reload to work and avoid console errors, you'll need to add `disableHostCheck: true`. Here's my final webpack config for one of the apps:

```
output: {
  filename: 'main.js',
  publicPath: '/app/app1',
},
devServer: {
  disableHostCheck: true,
  historyApiFallback: {
    index: '/app/app1',
  },
  port: 5000,
  publicPath: '/app/app1',
},
```